# Web starter kit & php

Tags: php

how can I use php files using the Google web starter kit? I discovered today the Web-Starter-Kit from Google and I'm trying to get familiar with it. It works great but now I add some php code into the basic.html file and it does show in the preview file but in the /dist/ directory where the final code awaits it doesn't appear.

My question is how can I use php files using the Google web starter kit?

Comment: you cannot until you made some edit in htaccess file.

Comment: and what changes would those be @NullPoiиteя ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is? Are you asking, "how can I use php files using the Google web starter kit? (related to locally hosting the site)" or "why does my html file not show the php content? (related to the misnaming of your file: already answered by pbdabholkar)"?

Comment: @CourtneyBodi the first question. How can I use php files using the Google web starter kit? Because I rename the files to .php and then, when I save them; all the php code disappears.

Comment: @Javittoxs Have done web development with a local host before? i.e. have you done web development with PHP before? If so, how have you hosted the site locally? e.g. MAMP

Answer (score 0):

You should use files with extension (.php) for writing PHP code. Try changing basic.html to basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

You should design the layout as normal html5 and css3 pages. Then make those static dynamic pages by replacing with php code.

Design different layout as static html pages first and then convert it to dynamic websites an easy way.